# Non unique values in R, CSV due to an unseen dot for white space in a character column values

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am trying to find unique species in a (large) dataset but it is returning same name twice within the unique() result.

```
TestData <- read.csv("Data\\TestData.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

unique(TestData$Species)

[1] "Amblyeleotris aurora"  "Amblyeleotris aurora"  "Cetoscarus bicolor"    "Cetoscarus bicolor"    "Cephalopholis polleni"
[6] "Cephalopholis polleni"
```

There are no spelling mis-match between the same species returned as non-unique and when I look at the csv file, they all look the same. However, when I copy the names to R console or to a script, there is red `.` that separate Genus and Species for one. Like `Amblyeleotris.aurora`.

This could be a problem with the csv file, but the dot doesn't appear when I view the file in Notepad++ nor in MS excel. However, the equality check in MS Excel evaluates to false when done for same species (i.e "Amblyeleotris aurora" with "Amblyeleotris aurora").

As mentioned, this is more likely to be a problem with csv, but I would like to find if there is a way to overcome this within R.

My apologies in advance if this has been already answered somewhere or if this is too simple a task to ask here, but I haven't found any solutions to this on stack or internet.

Here is the link to sample TestData csv file for reproducing the example and screenshot of ScriptPanel for showing the red dot.

[TestData.csv file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tDk7njupJ3Lp6Y0JvWaW1smK3b5d62Tw)

[image]

Cheers
Shimal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those red dots are indicating that you have [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) (NBSP) in your file.

In R you can convert all the NBSP's in the Species column to regular spaces with this line:

```
TestData$Species <- gsub("[[:space:]]", " ", TestData$Species)
```

And now your unique call will indicate that all the spaces are the same:

```
> unique(TestData$Species)
[1] "Amblyeleotris aurora"  "Cetoscarus bicolor"   
[3] "Cephalopholis polleni"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the non-graphic characters with a space:

```
dd <- read.csv("testdata.csv")
dd$Species <- gsub("[^[:graph:]]", " ", dd$Species)
unique(dd)
```

giving:

```
                Species
1  Amblyeleotris aurora
3    Cetoscarus bicolor
5 Cephalopholis polleni
```